# Javascript get current time with milliseconds with custom timezone

Tags: javascript

I wanted to get current time with milliseconds in javascript with my custom timezone.

The following code works fine:

```
var nDate = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: 'Asia/Calcutta'
});
```

But how do I also get milliseconds with above?

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMilliseconds();
```

This gives milliseconds of default timezone. I want with Asia/Calcutta.

Comment: Doubtful any timezone on the planet has a millisecond offset from any other.

Comment: do you mean to get something like "9/6/2018, 10:39:53.123 AM" ? I don't see any option for that, but they can be added to the result string, or use a library

Comment: You probably want to use a date library for this.. JS built-in dates are terrible.

Comment: which library ?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/